# How to get PhoneNumber from Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Customers.Customer?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

How to get PhoneNumber from Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Customers.Customer which is in CustomerDetailsComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dotPeeking some of XC code and looks like it should do the trick:

```
var customerDetails = customer.GetComponent<CustomerDetailsComponent>();
var view = customerDetails.View?.ChildViews?.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name.Equals("Details", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) as EntityView;
if (view != null)
{
   ExtendedCustomerPropertiesPolicy propertiesPolicy = context.GetPolicy<CustomerPropertiesPolicy>();    
   customerDetailsModel.PhoneNumber = view.Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertiesPolicy.PhoneNumber)?.Value;
}
```